# Token service not replacing text with term as a token

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9, tokens

I'm trying to use the token service to replace a piece of text using a Taxonomy Term.

Example:
Hi [term:field_first_name], ...

The term is getting loaded correctly, but the text is not changing:

```php
    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);

    $token_service = \Drupal::token();
    $text = $token_service->replace($text, [
        'term' => $term,
    ]);

    print_r($text);
```

The print returns: 
Hi [term:field_first_name], ... 
instead of: 
Hi John, ...

I'm currently using drupal version 9.3.2.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure *field_first_name* is a field added to taxonomy terms? It seems more a user field, by its name.

Comment: @apaderno Thank you for your answer, but it is a field, I just wanted to simplify the example.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal out-of-the-box has only basic token support, which can replace core entity standard fields like `[term:name]` or `[term:description]`.

Configured fields, usually those with a prefix `field_`, need the module [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) to be installed. Then `[term:field_first_name]` will be replaced, if the field exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know i didn't mention this, but i didn't want to rely on modules, thought it was already built in. I chose another path, looped through term: ```foreach($term as $field_name => $_)``` and then just used str_replace, to replace the text with the field names

Comment: I agree Drupal site owners should not install large amounts of modules, including beta or dev versions. But there are a few standard modules you can and should use if you need the functionality. And modules like Token can be installed and uninstalled with very low risk because they don't change the database schema.